# Get Webpack chunk url as string when using dynamic imports

Tags: javascript, webpack

With Webpack I can load a module like this:

```
import(moduleName).then(_ => {})
```

However I would only like to get the URL of the chunk, not actually load it. Is that possible?

Comment: I haven't actually tried chunking in webpack but I thought it placed some specific requirements on the output structure such that the chunks are all located relative to each other, in which case could you not derive `moduleName`'s url from the script you're currently in?

Comment: My actual code uses promise loader and `"dir/" + someVar`. Loading the module works fine. Webpack generates an ID for the chunk, but I'm not sure how to get that id.

Comment: Could you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Webpack 5 by re-using the [Worker Plugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/e2f1592f7e4d8f0578e5bb23d6a863b4a2b5f309/lib/dependencies/WorkerPlugin.js) with module.parser.

```js
// utils/chunk-url.js
export function ChunkUrl(url) { return url; }
```

Webpack config:

```js
webpackConfig.module = {
  parser: {
    javascript: {
      worker: ["ChunkUrl from ~/utils/chunk-url", "..."]
    }
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```js
import { ChunkUrl } from '~/utils/chunk-url';

// .../chunks/[hash].js
const ScriptUrl = new ChunkUrl(new URL('/path/to/file.js', import.meta.url));
```

The file will go through a child compiler like a dynamic import, but only the URL is returned.